# How to install and setup VNC on a fresh Install of Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS?

Tags: vnc, tightvncserver

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I've installed TigerVNC server and have attempted to remote connect using various VNC viewers, all resulting the same - black screen.

As of now I'm successfully connected via RDP from a Windows 10 Pro machine.

I'm setting up my Ubuntu box as a headless fileserver and I can't interrupt any processes, which is what RDP forces me to do by logging out of the session in order to log in.

I'll be more than happy to nuke TigerVNC for another VNC server, anything to get this working 100%.

As of now, this is the output I receive when I use vncserver:

```
    root@home:/home/seed# vncserver
 
New 'home:4 (root)' desktop at :4 on machine home
 
Starting applications specified in /etc/X11/Xvnc-session
Log file is /root/.vnc/home:4.log
 
Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /root/.vnc/passwd :4 to connect to the VNC server.
 
 
vncserver: Failed command '/etc/X11/Xvnc-session': 256!
 
=================== tail -15 /root/.vnc/home:4.log ===================
 
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.10.0 - built Apr  9 2020 06:49:31
Copyright (C) 1999-2019 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12008000, The X.Org Foundation
 
 
Sun Jan 17 21:15:38 2021
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on local interface(s), port 5904
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
X connection to :4 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
Killing Xtigervnc process ID 8121... which seems to be deadlocked. Using SIGKILL!
 
=========================================================================
 
Starting applications specified in /etc/X11/Xvnc-session has failed.
Maybe try something simple first, e.g.,
    tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm
```

Please help!

Thank you

Comment: where you able to resolve this? if yes please tell how